# Как в Javascript узнать полную высоту страницы document.documentElement?

Tags: javascript, html

Не высоту окна браузера, не видимую часть экрана, а именно полную высоту страницы от самого верха до низа.

Comment: вероятно подойдет: [`document.documentElement.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)

Comment: Уж точно нет...

Comment: почему, вы попробовали?

Comment: Только что.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147768/873481

```
var body = document.body,
    html = document.documentElement;

var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
                       html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
```

Comment: document.body.scrollHeight подошло! Спасибо.

Comment: @Lesperanza
Хорошо!) Только учитывайте, что в оригинальном ответе сказано про крос-браузерность, соответственно и приведенный код.